# Android LongClick Instagram

Tags: android, recyclerview, instagram

В инстаграме есть долгое нажатие на элемент - блюрится фон и на главный экран выступает картинка

Картинка или не картинка - все равно

Насколько я понимаю это fragment или какой-то продвинутый alertdialog

Вопрос в том, как сделать такое же, есть ли библиотеки и как это вообще называется и как такое можно вызвать из адаптера RecyclerView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: диалог такое не сделает. вам нужно добавлять View поверх ActivityDecor.

Comment: есть готовое решение [Blur Dialog](https://github.com/lany192/BlurDialog). Можете посмотреть реализацию и сделать свое решение. Как туда вставить картинку вы представление думаю имеете.

Comment: вопрос может содержать только одну проблему, если вы не знаете, как вызвать диалог при клике на айтем списка - задайте другой вопрос